# Changing column length will effect view in any way?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, view

If I change a column length of a table that I used in a view, will this effect the view in any way?

Note: I am using Sql Server 2008

Comment: That may depend on how you create the view and whether it's an indexed view. Could you add the statements creating the view and its indexes?

Comment: I created a simple view and used select statement in it to give only read access to someone

Comment: If you have created the view with schemabinding (required for indexing) then you won't be able to make the change without first dropping the view, if you haven't then the change will simply be cascaded to the view, so yes it will affect the view. Although you may need to run [sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx) to refresh the meta data.

Comment: After changes and without refreshing the view, will it be usable?

Comment: Yes, [see this simple example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf241/1)

Comment: @GarethD yes thanks.. kindly post your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have created the view with schemabinding (required for indexing) then you won't be able to make the change without first dropping the view, if you haven't then the change will simply be cascaded to the view, so yes it will affect the view. Although you may need to run [sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx) to refresh the meta data. The [online documentation states](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx):

> If a view is not created with the SCHEMABINDING clause, sp_refreshview should be run when changes are made to the objects underlying the view that affect the definition of the view. Otherwise, the view might produce unexpected results when it is queried.

I am currently struggling to find scenarios where changing a length and not running `sp_refreshview' produces unexpected results. With this simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (Col VARCHAR(10));
INSERT dbo.T (Col) VALUES (REPLICATE('X', 10));
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.V
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.T;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.V;

ALTER TABLE dbo.T ALTER COLUMN Col VARCHAR(30);
INSERT dbo.T (Col) VALUES (REPLICATE('X', 30));

SELECT *
FROM dbo.V;
```

It will still be usable after the change has been made, even if `sp_refreshview` has not been run [as demonstrated here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bf241/1) - The second select from `dbo.V` will still give the full 30 characters of the second row. **However** I would still advise executing it, it cannot hurt!! If you check the meta data after the change:

```
SELECT max_length
FROM sys.columns
WHERE name = 'Col'
AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.V', 'V');
```

The length will still be 10 after the change. Just as an example to show the kind of things to expext when not calling `sp_refreshview`, when running this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (Col VARCHAR(10));
INSERT dbo.T (Col) VALUES (REPLICATE('X', 10));
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.V
AS
SELECT *
FROM dbo.T;
GO
SELECT *
FROM dbo.V;

ALTER TABLE dbo.T ADD Col2 VARCHAR(30);
INSERT dbo.T (Col2) VALUES (REPLICATE('X', 30));

SELECT *
FROM dbo.V;
```

On the second select [you will not see the column `Col2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/63c70/1). I would however blame the author of the view in this case for using `SELECT *`!!!